# Implement custom partitioner in kafka .net

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to use kafka from .net application. I have created producer and consumer using .net. It is working fine.

But i have to use kafka for real time processing of file. So i am little bit confused. What should be the architecture that i need to follow and how to design the kafka application, that it is fault tolerance?

I have multiple id for file, and file can come anytime , in any number of files. So i want to use hashing algorithm to distribute the kafka partition load in different partition.

I googled many time but not get the application or sample to use this functionality in  .net application.

So please help me in designing and implementing the desired algorithm using .net.

basically we have endpoints (webservices) that is given to client and client push the file in regular interval, we have window service that regularly read file from db and parse the file for further processing. all application are in .net . we want to put file in kafka and consumer (window service )will read the file from kafka. Producer will be our ends points

Comment: Kafka isn't designed for file processing, rather message processing. For example, if you send one line at a time, then how would you know where one file starts and ends? Does order really matter? And Kafka has a default max message limit of 1MB, so do you have files larger than that are planing to send the whole thing as a message?

Comment: File processing is done through window service. I am planning to send whole thing as a message. Just to implement real time processing of file.

Comment: I would personally recommend you look into Filebeat or Fluentbit for this rather than a raw Kafka producer. Don't reinvent the wheel here. Though, again, you'll need to make sure you understand that Kafka has a default max message size